# Igros Kodesh on Chanukah: advice for during exile

Tags: sources-mekorot, translation, chanuka, chabad, messianic-redemption

The Lubavitcher Rebbe in [Igros Kodesh](https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/2987612/jewish/page.htm) talks about why the chanukah candle has 8 candles, and the menorah 7. But then, the Rebbe says “from this it is clear that the chanukah candles have a general instruction for all Israelites during the time of exile”. - ומזה מובן שבנרות חנוכה יש הוראה כללית לבני ישראל בנוגע לזמן הגלות.

The Rebbe says:

> הנס שעשה הקב"ה בימי חנוכה להראות חיבתן של ישראל שמדליקים את נרות המנורה בשמן טהור דוקא, אע"פ שע"פ דין היו יכולים להדליק בשמן שאינו טהור – מהוה הוראה מלמעלה שבזמן הגלות יש צורך במסירת-נפש (שזהו הדוגמא לענין של נס ביחס לעבודת האדם) אפילו על ענין שיש למצוא לו היתר ע"פ שולחן-ערוך, ובזה מתבטאת חיבתן של ישראל, שמוסרים נפשם גם על דקדוק והידור בעניני תומ"צ שיהיו בתכלית השלימות, כבהדלקת המנורה באופן של טהרה דוקא.

As I understand, this piece (My Hebrew is still WIP) means that the fact that pure oil was used to light the candles, also has a deeper meaning/significance to our lives. E.g that we ourselves need to be "pure".

Furthermore, the Rebbe says:

> כך גם "בזמן הזה" – כאשר עוסקים בתורה אליבא דאמת, ומתוך ידיעה שזוהי "תורתך", תורתו של הקב"ה, ולכן אין מסכימים על פשרות, ולא מחפשים היתרים וכו', אלא עומדים בתוקף אפילו על פרט קטן, והיינו, שכאשר כוונת המנגד היא להרחיק מיהדות, אזי אין נפק"מ אם מדובר אודות שרוך נעל, או אודות חינוך שצריכים להחדיר לראש, על שניהם מוסר נפשו בשוה, אף שלהיותו "מעט" ו"חלש" אינו רואה איך יוכל ליישם את הדבר בפועל

I do not completely understand what lesson the Rebbe is teaching us here. Is there someone who could translate it for me, maybe that would help me understanding it better.

Piece that I am not understanding (can some translate this?):

> ומזה מובן, שגם ההודאה על הנס הוצרכה להיות ענין כללי, הקשור עם טהרת עם ישראל – שזוהי ההכנה לענין הגאולה, הן לגאולה פרטית בזמן פרטי (כהגאולה דחנוכה), והן לגאולה הכללית בביאת המשיח, כמובן ממאמר המשנה6 "אשריכם ישראל לפני מי אתם מטהרין ומי מטהר אתכם אביכם שבשמים, שנאמר7 וזרקתי עליכם מים טהורים וטהרתם" – שפסוק זה נאמר בגאולה העתידה, ומזה מוכח שגאולת עם ישראל תלוי' בענין הטהרה.
>
> הנס שעשה הקב"ה בימי חנוכה להראות חיבתן של ישראל שמדליקים את נרות
> המנורה בשמן טהור דוקא, אע"פ שע"פ דין היו יכולים להדליק בשמן שאינו טהור
> – מהוה הוראה מלמעלה שבזמן הגלות יש צורך במסירת-נפש (שזהו הדוגמא לענין
> של נס ביחס לעבודת האדם) אפילו על ענין שיש למצוא לו היתר ע"פ
> שולחן-ערוך, ובזה מתבטאת חיבתן של ישראל, שמוסרים נפשם גם על דקדוק
> והידור בעניני תומ"צ שיהיו בתכלית השלימות, כבהדלקת המנורה באופן של טהרה
> דוקא.
>
> כך גם "בזמן הזה" – כאשר עוסקים בתורה אליבא דאמת, ומתוך ידיעה שזוהי
> "תורתך", תורתו של הקב"ה, ולכן אין מסכימים על פשרות, ולא מחפשים היתרים
> וכו', אלא עומדים בתוקף אפילו על פרט קטן, והיינו, שכאשר כוונת המנגד היא
> להרחיק מיהדות, אזי אין נפק"מ אם מדובר אודות שרוך נעל, או אודות חינוך
> שצריכים להחדיר לראש, על שניהם מוסר נפשו בשוה, אף שלהיותו "מעט" ו"חלש"
> אינו רואה איך יוכל ליישם את הדבר בפועל,

Comment: Another principle taught by the Rebbe is that the Avodah of our holy nation on Chanuka brought into the world a new power that innocence can never be lost. No matter how spoiled, a person's innocence is untouchable and can be brought back. May I recommend learning Mei Channukah. A great discussion on how the miracle of Channuka had to fulfil paradoxical conditions, and therefore was truly miraculous, beyond nature or reason and Hashem Himself made it happen.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for pointing it out. Where can Mei Channukah be found? I can't remember it's a maamar, right?

Comment: https://beta.kehot.com/kuntres-mai-chanukah

Comment: Found it: https://hebrewbooks.org/58856

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps:

"And from this it may be understood that also the thanks given for the miracle needed to be a general thing [inyan klali], connected to the purification of the Nation of Yisrael - for that is a preparation for the redemption [geulah], both for the person redemption of the personal time (such as the redemption of Chanukah) and for the general redemption during the coming of Mashiach, as is understood from what is stated in the [mishna](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Yoma.8.9?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) "How fortunate are you, Israel; before Whom are you purified, and Who purifies you? It is your Father in Heaven as it is stated: “And I will sprinkle purifying water upon you, and you shall be purified”" - for this verse was said with regards to the future redemption, and from here it is proven that the redemption of Yisrael depends on purity.

The miracle that the Holy One, Blessed is He did during the days of Chanukah to show the love of Yisrael that light the menorah candles with pure oil [as opposed to other substances], though by law they could have used impure oil - is a statement from above that during the time of the exile there is a need for giving one's life [mesirat nefesh] (which is an example for the idea of a miracle in relation to the labor of man) even with regards to a place where he would be able to find himself a leniency [heter] according to the Shulchan Aruch, and from this we can see the love of Yisrael, who give themselves up even for stringencies and beautification (hidur) of keeping Torah and Mitzvot to the fullest, such as lighting the menorah with specifically pure oil.

And so also during "this time" [hazman hazeh] - when one toils in Torah in the turest manner, and via the knowledge that this is "Your Torah", the Torah of the Holy One, Blessed is He, and therefore there is no agreeing on compromises, and no searching for leniencies [heterim] etc, rather - upholding forcefully even the smallest detail, meaning, that when the purpose of the antagonist is to distance from Judaism, so there is no implication whether we're talking about a shoelace, or education that must be drilled into the head - on both one must give his life equally, even if he is "few" and "weak" and cannot see how he would actively be able to implement this."

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. +1